# Photoshop canvas and artboard resize and export issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I'm new to design in general and I'm designing a prototype for the web.I'm creating my files in photoshop and exporting them into invision. When I export my files from photoshop into invision, they appear far too large in the browser.

The dimensions I want are 1920 x 1080 px. The artboards I'm exporting are the correct size (1920 x 1080) but when I export them, they're exporting as 2944 x2144. Photoshop tells me that the canvas size is 2944 x2144 but whenever I try to change the canvas size to 1920 x 1080 px, my changes do not hold. Even though photoshop reports the canvas size to exceed the artboard size, I don't see the typical grid that appears when this is the case.

Is there something I can do in photoshop to correct the issue I'm having?

Here's a link to a gif of me attempting to change the size of my canvas

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq0Qm.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had something similar, I think. Not sure exactly why, but seemed the artboard had been linked to the canvas, which wasn't the same thing. Anyway, resolution was to right-click artboard, under the layers panel, and un-link or something (I can't even go back and check, as I know not what I had done!)

Comment: In the layers panel when I right clicked on my artboard there was an option to "ungroup artboard" and when I selected this I was able to achieve the sizing I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @huntercolgate Please mark as answered if you are satisfied with the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting the same problem. I found a solution: when you create a new file you have to make sure horizontal and vertical sizes are UNLINKED. 
By unlinking the width and Height. (Just click on the little chain icon in between the values. And Uncheck the bock with the name of ARTBOARD.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem: when I tried to make an artboard from a group or layers, the artboard canvas size was not the same as the group's canvas size. 
Trying to problem solve it, I found the issue. It was an adjustment layer that I had in one of the layer sets. Once I turned it off, the artboard canvas size matched the group's canvas size.
Not sure if this will solve your problem, but it sure as heck solved this one bug.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the artboard and select ungroup objects. This allowed me to resize and crop my artboard without any issues saving a gif

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, a 8.5x11" psd becoming 30+" upon exporting. Here is what I did to make it work.
Make an artboard that is the same size and position as the canvas. The artboard tool can be found by rightclicking on the move tool. 
Then File > Export > Artboards to Files, and click on the jpeg option and export. 
Now open the jpg in photoshop and you'll see the size is correct, ready to print.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue, where different types of exports seem to result in different-sized images, either based on the artboard size or the canvas size. The best way to be sure all exports are the same would be to set both to the same dimensions.

I'm not sure how familiar you are with Photoshop, but just so we are on the same page:
- Canvas size can be set in **Image > Canvas Size...**.
- Artboard size can be set with the Artboard Tool (Long-click on the Move Tool and select Artboard Tool)

The solution is actually quite simple. With the Artboard Tool selected, click the Settings/Cog icon in the Tool Options bar at the top of the screen. A few checkboxes will appear, and the one we want to select is the self-explanatory "**ShrinkWrap Canvas on Save**."

[Artboard Tool Setting: ShrinkWrap Canvas on Save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbocT.png)

Check that box, save your document, and that should do the trick! To verify that the canvas size has been updated, check it at **Image > Canvas Size...**.